# How to check for AM|PM through JsonArray

Tags: android, json

/*{"chogadia":[{"ChogadiaName":5,"StartTime":"5:25:50 AM","EndTime":"7:9:13 AM","Effect":"Inauspicious Chogadia"},{"ChogadiaName":6,"StartTime":"7:9:13 AM","EndTime":"8:52:37 AM","Effect":"Auspicious Chogadia"},{"ChogadiaName":7,"StartTime":"8:52:37 AM","EndTime":"10:36:1 AM","Effect":"Inauspicious Chogadia"},{"ChogadiaName":1,"StartTime":"10:36:1 AM","EndTime":"12:19:24 AM","Effect":"Inauspicious Chogadia"},{"ChogadiaName":2,"StartTime":"12:19:24 PM","EndTime":"14:2:48 PM","Effect":"Auspicious Chogadia"},{"ChogadiaName":3,"StartTime":"14:2:48 PM","EndTime":"15:46:12 PM","Effect":"Auspicious Chogadia"},{"ChogadiaName":4,"StartTime":"15:46:12 PM","EndTime":"17:29:36 PM","Effect":"Auspicious Chogadia"},{"ChogadiaName":5,"StartTime":"17:29:36 PM","EndTime":"19:13:0 PM","Effect":"Inauspicious Chogadia"},{"ChogadiaName":3,"StartTime":"19:13:0 PM","EndTime":"20:29:36 PM","Effect":"Auspicious Chogadia"}]}*/

public class ChogadiaParser {

```
public static  ArrayList<Chogadia> mList=new ArrayList<Chogadia>();
public static Chogadia mChogadia;
public static String response,chogadia;
public static String Lucky="Auspicious Chogadia";
public static String UnLucky="Inauspicious Chogadia";
public static String chogadiaName,startTime,endTime;


public static void GroupResult(String url){

    try{
      JSONArray jArray;
      JSONObject jObject;

     response=GetJsonObject.sendRequest(url);

     if(response == null){
            return;
        }

     jObject=new JSONObject(response);
     jArray=jObject.getJSONArray("chogadia");
     mList.clear();
     for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

         mChogadia=new Chogadia();
         jObject=jArray.getJSONObject(i);
         mChogadia.SetChogadiaName(jObject.getString("ChogadiaName"));
         mChogadia.SetStartTime(jObject.getString("StartTime"));
         mChogadia.SetEndTime(jObject.getString("EndTime"));
         mChogadia.SetEffect(jObject.getString("Effect"));
         mList.add(mChogadia);



         if(mathcTime(jObject.getString("StartTime"),jObject.getString("EndTime"))){

              chogadiaName=jObject.getString("ChogadiaName");
              startTime=jObject.getString("StartTime");
              endTime=jObject.getString("EndTime");
              System.out.println("Matched Name Is: " + jObject.getString("ChogadiaName")+"" + jObject.getString("StartTime") );
              Log.e("String time", jObject.getString("ChogadiaName"));


         }
     } 

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();    
    }
```

}

```
   private static boolean mathcTime(String stime,String eTime) {
    SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");

    try {
        Date ct = new Date();
        Date st = ft.parse(stime);
        Date et=ft.parse(eTime);;

        long currentTime = ((ct.getHours()*60)*60) + (ct.getMinutes()*60) + (ct.getSeconds());
        long startTime = ((st.getHours()*60)*60) + (st.getMinutes()*60) + (st.getSeconds());
        long endTime = ((et.getHours()*60)*60) + (et.getMinutes()*60) + (et.getSeconds());

        if(currentTime>=startTime && currentTime<=endTime){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
 return false;
}
```

}
please help me out from this question...here i am matching device is equals to fetching time(fetching time shows as comment in upper side)and show the chogadiaName.it is working but prblm is that is not match time AM it starts matching from PM only..please help me .

Comment: You seem to be using `24 hours` system and also write `AM` `PM`

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @ Sunil Mishra-thanks for your reply give me an example for this how to do this...

Comment: @ Sunil Mishra-Thanks for your reply please suggest me how to do this ..

Comment: @TharakaNirmana-pblm is that i m fetched the time from server which is i posted upper side as comment.i have to match that time from device time and show chogadia name..prblm is that when i matched the time from device time it match from PM not AM..

Answer (score 0):

try date format like this

```
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
```

for more details [Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: @Ketan-but it not working give suggest me any other answer..thanks for your reply..